# Following TypeScript tutorial with modifications - why is my InMemoryDBService implementation not working?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I am following the [tutorial here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html) but modifying to hold 'Staff' instances rather than 'Heroes'. It seems that this class is breaking my code - I have come to this conclusion as if I comment out the line `InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService),` from the imports section of app.module.ts, the webpage loads without its contents which are required from InMemoryDataService - can anybody tell me what the problem is with this class? 
Previous to this, I was using a constant array of type Staff that was exported to hold data (as the tutorial instructed). The rest of my code is the same as the tutorial with modifications to handle a "Service" object instead of a "Hero" object.

Below is the InMemoryDataService class

```
import { InMemoryDbService } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
  createDb() {
    let staff = [
        { id: 11, firstName:'Jeremy', lastName:'Phan', email:'email', phone:444},
        { id: 12, firstName:'Jacob', lastName:'Phantom', email:'email', phone:444},
        { id: 13, firstName:'Yi', lastName:'Hi', email:'email', phone:444},
        { id: 14, firstName:'Steven', lastName:'Hawkings', email:'itguy@world.com', phone:1300655506},
        { id: 15, firstName:'Calvin', lastName:'Chan', email:'melbournestorm.calvinchan@gmail.com', phone:14355555532},
        { id: 16, firstName:'Cameron', lastName:'Tall', email:'melbournestorm.camerontall@gmail.com', phone:23452345},
        { id: 17, firstName:'Alex', lastName:'Flairdiddy', email:'melbournestorm.alexflair@gmail.com', phone:234523452}
    ];
    return {staff};
  }
}
```

Staff class

```
export class Staff
{
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
    phone: number;
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: try to set class variables to `public` => `public id: number` etc. and place it in constructor.

Comment: I am stuck at this very point in the tutorial too.  Did you solve it?  I can see that there is a provider reference and can find that reference in the backend.service file but don't know enough to debug it properly yet.

Comment: Nope, sorry mate. It was for work experience and the work experience ended before I got anywhere with it. Good luck!